# Convert the linux command to Cim windows command

Tags: wmic, cim

What is the equivalent command using Cim instance ?

`wmic cpu list /format:list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ***Powershell*** , you can use like this :

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor
```

If you want to get all infos about CPU, you can use this command :

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Select *
```

And if you want to get and choose a specific property, just type this command to look what you want to select as property :

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Get-Member
```

---

```
Name                                    MemberType  Definition                                                                                                                       
----                                    ----------  ----------                                                                                                                       
Clone                                   Method      System.Object ICloneable.Clone()                                                                                                 
Dispose                                 Method      void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()                                                                                       
Equals                                  Method      bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                   
GetCimSessionComputerName               Method      string GetCimSessionComputerName()                                                                                               
GetCimSessionInstanceId                 Method      guid GetCimSessionInstanceId()                                                                                                   
GetHashCode                             Method      int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                
GetObjectData                           Method      void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)...
GetType                                 Method      type GetType()                                                                                                                   
ToString                                Method      string ToString()                                                                                                                
AddressWidth                            Property    uint16 AddressWidth {get;}                                                                                                       
Architecture                            Property    uint16 Architecture {get;}                                                                                                       
AssetTag                                Property    string AssetTag {get;}                                                                                                           
Availability                            Property    uint16 Availability {get;}                                                                                                       
Caption                                 Property    string Caption {get;}                                                                                                            
Characteristics                         Property    uint32 Characteristics {get;}                                                                                                    
ConfigManagerErrorCode                  Property    uint32 ConfigManagerErrorCode {get;}                                                                                             
ConfigManagerUserConfig                 Property    bool ConfigManagerUserConfig {get;}                                                                                              
CpuStatus                               Property    uint16 CpuStatus {get;}                                                                                                          
CreationClassName                       Property    string CreationClassName {get;}                                                                                                  
CurrentClockSpeed                       Property    uint32 CurrentClockSpeed {get;}                                                                                                  
CurrentVoltage                          Property    uint16 CurrentVoltage {get;}                                                                                                     
DataWidth                               Property    uint16 DataWidth {get;}                                                                                                          
Description                             Property    string Description {get;}                                                                                                        
DeviceID                                Property    string DeviceID {get;}                                                                                                           
ErrorCleared                            Property    bool ErrorCleared {get;}                                                                                                         
ErrorDescription                        Property    string ErrorDescription {get;}                                                                                                   
ExtClock                                Property    uint32 ExtClock {get;}                                                                                                           
Family                                  Property    uint16 Family {get;}                                                                                                             
InstallDate                             Property    CimInstance#DateTime InstallDate {get;}                                                                                          
L2CacheSize                             Property    uint32 L2CacheSize {get;}                                                                                                        
L2CacheSpeed                            Property    uint32 L2CacheSpeed {get;}                                                                                                       
L3CacheSize                             Property    uint32 L3CacheSize {get;}                                                                                                        
L3CacheSpeed                            Property    uint32 L3CacheSpeed {get;}                                                                                                       
LastErrorCode                           Property    uint32 LastErrorCode {get;}                                                                                                      
Level                                   Property    uint16 Level {get;}                                                                                                              
LoadPercentage                          Property    uint16 LoadPercentage {get;}                                                                                                     
Manufacturer                            Property    string Manufacturer {get;}                                                                                                       
MaxClockSpeed                           Property    uint32 MaxClockSpeed {get;}                                                                                                      
Name                                    Property    string Name {get;}                                                                                                               
NumberOfCores                           Property    uint32 NumberOfCores {get;}                                                                                                      
NumberOfEnabledCore                     Property    uint32 NumberOfEnabledCore {get;}                                                                                                
NumberOfLogicalProcessors               Property    uint32 NumberOfLogicalProcessors {get;}                                                                                          
OtherFamilyDescription                  Property    string OtherFamilyDescription {get;}                                                                                             
PartNumber                              Property    string PartNumber {get;}                                                                                                         
PNPDeviceID                             Property    string PNPDeviceID {get;}                                                                                                        
PowerManagementCapabilities             Property    uint16[] PowerManagementCapabilities {get;}                                                                                      
PowerManagementSupported                Property    bool PowerManagementSupported {get;}                                                                                             
ProcessorId                             Property    string ProcessorId {get;}                                                                                                        
ProcessorType                           Property    uint16 ProcessorType {get;}                                                                                                      
PSComputerName                          Property    string PSComputerName {get;}                                                                                                     
Revision                                Property    uint16 Revision {get;}                                                                                                           
Role                                    Property    string Role {get;}                                                                                                               
SecondLevelAddressTranslationExtensions Property    bool SecondLevelAddressTranslationExtensions {get;}                                                                              
SerialNumber                            Property    string SerialNumber {get;}                                                                                                       
SocketDesignation                       Property    string SocketDesignation {get;}                                                                                                  
Status                                  Property    string Status {get;}                                                                                                             
StatusInfo                              Property    uint16 StatusInfo {get;}                                                                                                         
Stepping                                Property    string Stepping {get;}                                                                                                           
SystemCreationClassName                 Property    string SystemCreationClassName {get;}                                                                                            
SystemName                              Property    string SystemName {get;}                                                                                                         
ThreadCount                             Property    uint32 ThreadCount {get;}                                                                                                        
UniqueId                                Property    string UniqueId {get;}                                                                                                           
UpgradeMethod                           Property    uint16 UpgradeMethod {get;}                                                                                                      
Version                                 Property    string Version {get;}                                                                                                            
VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled           Property    bool VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled {get;}                                                                                        
VMMonitorModeExtensions                 Property    bool VMMonitorModeExtensions {get;}                                                                                              
VoltageCaps                             Property    uint32 VoltageCaps {get;}                                                                                                        
PSConfiguration                         PropertySet PSConfiguration {AddressWidth, DataWidth, DeviceID, ExtClock, L2CacheSize, L2CacheSpeed, MaxClockSpeed, PowerManagementSupport...
PSStatus                                PropertySet PSStatus {Availability, CpuStatus, CurrentVoltage, DeviceID, ErrorCleared, ErrorDescription, LastErrorCode, LoadPercentage,...
```

---

And for example you want to select some of them :

---

```Powershell
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | 
    Select Caption,Manufacturer,Name,NumberOfLogicalProcessors,NumberOfCores,NumberOfEnabledCore,ProcessorType,DeviceID,AddressWidth,Architecture,CpuStatus,CurrentClockSpeed,CurrentVoltage,LoadPercentage,MaxClockSpeed
```